# error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-system.so.2.4

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dependencies, games, dynamic-linking

I downloaded a game from this link [space-logic-adventure](https://hckr.pl/space-logic-adventure/)

I found this error message when I tried to run it:

```
pascal@pascal-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:~/Computer/Games/Linux/space-logic-adventure-v1.2-linux-x64$ ./space-logic-adventure
./space-logic-adventure: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-system.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Before running it I installed this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you have to install the [relevant package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libsfml-system.so.2.4) with this library

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-system2.4
```

and other similar libraries using

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-window2.4 libsfml-graphics2.4 libsfml-audio2.4
```

or install all of them including development headers by

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

---

On newer Ubuntu versions (starting from 20.04 LTS) you have to download deb-packages from 18.04 LTS repository of such libraries manually by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsfml/libsfml-audio2.4_2.4.2+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsfml/libsfml-graphics2.4_2.4.2+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsfml/libsfml-network2.4_2.4.2+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsfml/libsfml-system2.4_2.4.2+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsfml/libsfml-window2.4_2.4.2+dfsg-4_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libsfml*.deb
```

and then enjoy the game.